# Height filling minipages in Beamer

Tags: beamer, minipage, height

I am trying to accurately center things in my Beamer frames with animations. For that purpose, I would like to use `minipages` with fixed height, which should be automatically inferred so that I do not have to guess for each frame what is the correct height to specify. I tried to do the following, but it does not work:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
        List
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Point 1
            \item<2-> Point 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \only<1>{
        \begin{minipage}[c][\fill]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            centered text
        \end{minipage}}
    \only<2>{
        \begin{minipage}[c][\fill]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \color{green}{\rule{4cm}{3cm}}
        \end{minipage}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Why is this not working and is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify the size of a box the *natural* size of a length is used (which is 0pt in the case of `\fill`).

I think you want something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Ilmenau}
\useoutertheme{smoothbars}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{minipage}{1\linewidth}
        List
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Point 1
            \item<2-> Point 2
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \only<1>{\vspace*{\fill}\par
        \begin{minipage}[c][.7\textheight][c]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            centered text
        \end{minipage}
        \par\vspace*{\fill}}
    \only<2>{\vspace*{\fill}\par
        \begin{minipage}[c][.7\textheight][c]{1\textwidth}
            \centering
            \color{green}{\rule{4cm}{3cm}}
        \end{minipage}
        \par\vspace*{\fill}}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if I do this, the minipages will have a constant height and therefore the text or rectangle will not be vertically centered in the space under the item list. What I was looking for is a way to adapt the height of the minipages so that it fits below the item list and down to the frame bottom border, resulting in a vertically centered content. Is it clearer ?

Comment: You can center the inner text of the minipage using `c` as one of the additional minipage options so that if you vertically center the minipage as a whole is contents will be vertically centred in the space. (TeX really doesn't know where it is on the page at the point it sets a box so measuring the space and making a box to fit is complicated and requires multiple passes (unless you know how to hook into beamer which must already be doing that to make overlays work, I suspect) but hooking into beamer internals has other problems:-)

Comment: Ok ... This is weird though, because if it is possible to vertically center the minipage, it means the size of the space where it is centered in known somehow.

Comment: It's known _later_ when the page is made up in the output routine That happens asynchronously with macro expansion and box setting.

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation. So how would you do the vertical centering of the minipages as a whole, in the example above ?

Comment: @AldurDisciple extra `c'` argument to centre the minipage contents and \vspace*{\fill} to centre the minipage see updated code in answer